# Ordenar por data

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony-2

Olhem é possível ordenar uma tabela por data em javascript, symfony2 ou jquery?

Eu tenho uma tabela com vários dados e registos e eu gostaria de ordenar os registos por data.

Comment: Da uma olhada se isso lhe ajuda: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Se você já enviou os dados ao cliente, deve-se enviá-los já ordenados ou fornecer alguma forma de ordenação com JavaScript ou jQuery. Se não os enviou, precisa ordenar com PHP ou diretamente pelo SQL. Descreva melhor o seu problema.

Comment: É o seguinte, imaginamos uma tabela com várias intervenções numa máquina, o que eu pretendo é ordenar essas intervenções pela data, de hoje para baixo.

Comment: É uma tabela igual há que está no link em baixo no Demo que eu pretendia, mas que em vez de ter de carregar nos campos para ordenar, a tabela aparece-se já ordenada por data. http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Voce pode simplesmente puxar os dados pela Data, e enviar para o cliente já ordenada

Comment: Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: @CatarinaSilvestre poste como você está buscando esses dados atualmente, e propomos uma alteração em cima disso.

Answer (score 1):

Usando symfony2 você já pode trazer os dados ordenados na consulta.

Existe várias formas de fazer, pode fazer a consulta diretamente na Controller ou criar um EntityRepository

Por exemplo na controller:

```
$em = $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SeuBundle:Post');

//voce pode filtrar por algum campo
$dados = $em->findBy(array('tipo'=>'AB'), array('data'=>'DESC')); //ou ASC

//ou você pode trazer todos os resultados somente ordenando
$dados = $em->findBy(array(), array('data'=>'DESC'));
```

Fonte: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html